# Rotating caption title together with table

Tags: tables, rotating

[image]

As presented in the above picture, when I use the command \rotatebox{90} to rotate a table the caption (title) of the table doesn't rotate. How can I make the title rotate with the table? Note that not the whole table is included in the below MWE.

```
   documentclass[12pt]{report}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{bigstrut}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{rotating}


        \begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
 \centering
  \caption{17 oldest associations of the Zurich gymnastics organization 1871 - 1911}
  \tiny
    \rotatebox{90}{ \begin{tabular}{lccc|ccccc|cc|cc}
    \hline
    \textbf{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{1871}} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{1886}}    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{1907}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1911}} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    Association & Active & Passive & Total & Active & Passive & Honorary & Mitturner & Total  & Active & Total & Active & Total \bigstrut\\
\hline
    Total & 556   & 89    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{645} & 507   & 519   & 284   & 19    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1'329} & 675   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4'246} & 729   & 5'101 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: `sidewaystable` instead of `table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already loading the `rotating` package, you could use that package's `sidewaystable` environment instead of the basic `table` environment. Be sure *not* to use the `\rotatebox` macro in addition to using a `sidewaystable` environment.

I would also recommend you omit all vertical lines and use the rule-drawing commands of the `booktabs` package to obtain well-spaced horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption{17 oldest associations of the Zurich gymnastics organization, 1871--1911} \label{tab:addlabel}%
\begin{tabular}{@{} lccc ccccc cc cc @{}}
\toprule
Association 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{1871}} 
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{1886}}    
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1907}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1911}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-9} 
\cmidrule(lr){10-11} \cmidrule(l){12-13}
& Active & Passive & Total & Active & Passive & Honorary 
& Mitturner & Total  & Active & Total & Active & Total \\
\midrule
Total & 556   & 89    & 645 & 507   & 519   & 284   & 19    
& 1'329 & 675   & 4'246 & 729   & 5'101 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}%
\end{document}
```